# reducing the number of email notifications sent by Gerrit

Tags: gerrit, email-notifications

I'm currently using Gerrit to manage a project, I've received complaints about how chatty gerrit is. Is there anyway to filter who gets which emails (i.e. code review owner gets all emails, while reviewers only get notified when added to a new code review or a new patchset is added)

I've looked into the project level notification settings but I'm not 100% sure how they work? (do they only apply to the project watchers? or to everyone involved in a code review in that project)

I understand that when using the REST API calls I can choose who to notify but not when making changes using the web interface.

Answer (score 4):

You can configure e-mail notifications in two different levels:

1) User level

Go to Settings > Watched Projects and add the project(s) which you want to receive notifications. You can also add a search expression to receive notifications "only if" a situation is satisfacted (e.g. branch:release). You can receive notifications for one (or more) of the following:

```
New Changes
New Patch Sets
All Comments
Submitted Changes
Abandoned Changes
```

2) Project level

Independent if users configured or not the first notification level, you can set projects to send notifications to users or groups if some pre defined situations (like the ones showed in the user level above) happens.

See [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-notify.html) more details about the e-mail notifications and how to configure the project level one.

Notes:

Although you can add more notifications using these methods, you can not remove the default existing notifications.

With Gerrit 2.15 you can [ignore and mute changes](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/intro-user.html#ignore). I think these new features can be very usefull to you.

Comment: would be nice to have a filter on Comments - since I would like to get notification only if there is +2 vote.

Comment: yea, that's exactly what I wanted to do, but I think to do that I'd have to suppress all gerrit notifications and hook into the particular gerrit events I want and send my own emails, which is frankly more effort than it's worth